# Xamarin.Form Picker from List

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Form and I have this Picker in my xaml file:

```
<Picker Title="Select Communities"
        ItemsSource="{Binding areas}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Description}" WidthRequest="400" x:Name="CommunityPicker" />
```

I am trying to bind this List I have: `List<AreaClass> areas = new List<AreaClass>();`

This list gets populated via api call and I can see it has 30 items in it, however nothing appears in my picker.

Here is my class:

```
public class AreaClass
    {
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is how its getting populated:

In code behind:

```
areas = webService.getAreas();
```

And here is the getAreas method:

```
public List<AreaClass> getAreas()
        {

            List<AreaClass> areas = new List<AreaClass>();

            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                AreaClass area = new AreaClass();

                                area.Area = reader["Area"].ToString();
                                area.Description = reader["Description"].ToString();

                                areas.Add(area);
                            }
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            return areas;

        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my Picker not getting populated?

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind to public properties.  Either make `areas` a public property

```
public List<AreaClass> areas { get; set; }
```

or explicitly assign `ItemsSource` in the code behind

```
CommunityPicker.ItemsSource = webService.getAreas();
```

Comment: This is weird....I keep getting an error saying CommunityPicker does not exists

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your solution

Comment: Yup, that worked....how do I get it display the Description from my Model?

Comment: @user979331 If you have solved this issue, please mark it as answer it will help others who have similar issue.Thanks.